# When I try to connect Azure into a BitBucket Git repository I receive the following error in the azure management portal

Tags: git, azure, deployment, bitbucket

When I try to connect Azure into a BitBucket Git repository I receive the following error in the azure management portal

```
GetSSHKey: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. You must make sure that you have administrator privileges for the repository.
```

I do have admin privileges, the only thing that is different is I have recently setup ssh between my laptop and this repository.

Comment: Do you still see this issue? If so, let's try to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: First let confirm if you are really an admin.   On bitbucket.org, select to repo in question and see if you can get the settings (gear logo) -> deploy keys.